# How to put variable inside JSON string in Inno Setup

Tags: json, inno-setup

I want to send a JSON string to a special webserver that accepts JSON in HTTP POST request.

How do I include a variable value inside the JSON string double quotes?

For instance:

```pascal
varStr := 'test';
jsonStr := '{"xyz":"{varStr}"}';
```

In the end I want `jsonStr` to be: `{"xyz":"test"}`

Comment: Thanks! It helped.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Format` function.

```pascal
varStr := 'test';
jsonStr := Format('{"xyz":"{%s}"}', [varStr]);
```

You can also use simple concatenation:

```pascal
jsonStr := '{"xyz":"' + varStr + '"}`;
```

I prefer the first, as it's cleaner and less prone to mistakes.